# How does a user insert a null in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, null

MS Access appears to support nulls in code, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to enter a null directly in a table.  This is maddening because once a field has had a figure entered in it, it can never be deleted/set to null.  Normally, allowing zero length strings would take care of this, but Access treats the XML export of a null and a zero length string differently.  A null eliminates the associated XML tag and a zero length string sends an empty tag.

Comment: How are you entering the data into the tables?  I have run an XML export with data that I have entered using a table view, and it successfully adds and removes the column as you suggested.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want to allow zero length strings?

Comment: There's no such thing as "directly in a table". You are probably referring to a form which is bound to a recordset, probably the one provided In the UI of whatever version of MS Access you are using. Or does 'directly' mean you are using SQL code?

Comment: @onedaywhen, I was referring to those things that access calls "tables".  Also, don't even bother going all tuple/relation on us when we're talking about MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't think this is an easily solvable problem and my original question was a little off target.  The problem isn't so much with nulls, although they are involved, as with the manner in which the table was originally created.  If you use an xsd file to create your tables you plan on exporting, something happens under the hood in Access that causes those fields to be treated a little differently than fields created with the editors.

The only solution I found was to create a new field in the table, rename the old field, copy the data from the old field to the new field and delete the old field.

After doing that, then blank fields that had data in them at one point are no longer included in the XML output.  It's probably not the best way to do this, and I still don't know exactly why it's happening, but at least I can get past the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Does setting the "Allow zero length string" option in the table definition help? It may force an empty string to be interpreted as NULL.

Comment: Not "may", but WILL. Unless you're using ZLS as a meaningful value that is distinct from Null, there is no reason for any field to allow the storage of ZLS's. It's certainly user unfriendly.

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about needing to do it in Datasheet view?  If you needed to do it in an update query, you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE test SET test.test = Null;
```

Comment: Yes, I was talking about doing it in the datasheet view.

Answer (score 2):

press ctrl-0 and a null is inserted.

Comment: This does not work with Access 2007.  How did you get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting all the characters will work, but Access is a bit fickle.  Hitting backspace or delete will not work unless there are characters in the field.  I find it is best to enter a few characters, select all, and hit delete, change focus and change the record.  After all the above, if you run a query looking for "is null" the record will be found.

Comment: Had some success entering a few characters as suggested then using F2 to select followed by delete, but it doesn't work consistently

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually looking for a way for a layperson to do the entry directly in a table.  In MSSQL you can simply press ctrl-0 and a null is inserted.  Deleting all the characters doesn't appear to work.  Instead of a null, you are left with an empty string.  They are not treated the same by Access for export purposes.

I think what I'm going to wind up doing is creating an xslt file to use during export that  eliminates empty tags.  That way the user can't really tell the difference.

It sure would be nice, though, to be able to key in a null.

Comment: What version of Access are you using?  As I mentioned in my comments on your original post, I have implemented the behaviour you are requesting.

Answer (score -1):

Just delete all characters in the column and access will insert a null value for you if the coumn allows it.

Comment: Not if the field is set to allow zero-length strings.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton for me it works as specified by @bang. I have `NOT NULL varchar` column in a linked table to SQL Server & `allow zero-length strings = yes` in Access. Still when I delete the text it does not insert empty string, instead gives null insert error that the column is not of type variant.

Comment: I see, the behavior is different for ODBC linked tables http://stackoverflow.com/a/22203637/2224701