# MS Access error when connected to ODBC

Tags: ms-access, odbc

When attempting to add a line in MS Access 2010 in a field which is Varchar not null i am getting the error "you tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a variant data type"

I am using an ODBC connection from an sql database which allows the empty value in the table but not when trying to add rows in access

I believe this to have been a common fault in 2007 from what i have read?

Firstly does anyone know if there is a simple work around for this problem?

Secondly I can't see a patch for this on the microsoft website i am currently using office 2010 professional plus version 14.0.7015.1000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Access, when entering a value "directly" into a table (either in Datasheet View or in a bound form), simply leaving the cell/control empty will attempt to insert a NULL value. If the corresponding column in the underlying table does not allow NULL values then the insert will fail.

The workaround for that is to type

```
""
```

into the cell/control to specify an empty string (which is not the same as a NULL value). I just tested this on an ODBC linked table against SQL Server 2008 R2 from Access 2010 and it worked.

Comment: Hey Thompson , this was being used for our process similarly with Access to SQL Server , but now it seems like only one entry is not accepting the ""  while rest of the rows are good , only one row is not accepting and throwing out an error

Answer (score 0):

user2615341, it seems that MS SQL Server jumps in before any other event can be triggered (BeforeUpdate/Click/LostFocus...). My personal experience leads me to suggest you that you have to build a proxy type/class and work with a disconnected form if you want to have full control of what's happening.